# Google Cloud CLI - issue listing all resources of a proect

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to list of the resources assigned to aGoogle Cloud Project using CLI

When I run the following command:

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=projects/projtest
```

it return an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.asset.search-all-resources) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project 'project:xxx-backup-342714' not found or deleted.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: googleapis.com
  metadata:
    consumer: projects/xxx-backup-342714
    service: cloudasset.googleapis.com
  reason: USER_PROJECT_DENIED
```

If I remember well I removed the xxx-backup-342714 from the Google Cloude Console but i'm not sure of that.
Anyway how I can solve this issue and list the resources?

Answer (score 1):

Run `gcloud config list` to list your current account and project and make sure your account has permissions to your project `xxx-backup-342714`

For detailed issue, try running

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=projects/<PROJECT> --verbosity debug
```

Also make sure `API [cloudasset.googleapis.com]` is enabled for your project